# How to solve this second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation:
$$\frac {d^2u}{dx^2}=-u$$
I know in hindsight that the solution is 
$$u(x)=a\cdot cos(x)+b\cdot sin(x)$$
because the second derivative of that equals its negation. 
However, I only know that this must be the solution in hindsight, after someone else told me.

**So my question is:** How would one go about deriving this solution, if one has no idea yet that the solution looks like a sum of cosines and sines?

Comment: On which variables depend on the function "u"?

Comment: let's say only x.

Comment: Are you familiar with using exponentials to solve such equations? Because you can get the sine and cosine from an imaginary exponential

Comment: No I am not, that sounds promising. I am aware that $e^{ix}=cos(x)+i\cdot sin(x)$, but I don't know how to use it to solve this.

Comment: What is delta ($\delta$), in your case?

Comment: $\frac {\delta ^2u}{\delta x\delta x}$ is just the second derivative of u with respect to x.

Answer (score 1):

To solve:

$$\frac{\text{d}^2u(x)}{\text{d}x^2}=-u(x)\Longleftrightarrow u''(x)=-u(x)$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L}_x\left[u''(x)\right]_{(\text{s})}=-\mathcal{L}_x\left[u(x)\right]_{(\text{s})}$$

Use:

1. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[u''(x)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{s}^2\text{U}(\text{s})-\text{s}u(0)-u'(0)$$
2. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[u(x)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{U}(\text{s})$$

So, we get:

$$\text{s}^2\text{U}(\text{s})-\text{s}u(0)-u'(0)=-\text{U}(\text{s})$$

Solving for $\text{U}(\text{s})$:

$$\text{U}(\text{s})=\frac{\text{s}u(0)+u'(0)}{1+\text{s}^2}$$

Now, with inverse Laplace transform we find:

$$u(x)=u(0)\cos(x)+u'(0)\sin(x)$$

---

HINT, for solving it another way:

$$u''(x)=-u(x)\Longleftrightarrow\int u'(x)u''(x)\space\text{d}x=\int-u'(x)u(x)\space\text{d}x$$

Now, use:

- Substitute $s=u'(x)$ and $\text{d}s=u''(x)\space\text{d}x$:
  $$\int u'(x)u''(x)\space\text{d}x=\int s\space\text{d}s=\frac{s^2}{2}+\text{C}=\frac{u'(x)^2}{2}+\text{C}$$
- Substitute $p=u(x)$ and $\text{d}p=u'(x)\space\text{d}x$:
  $$\int -u'(x)u(x)\space\text{d}x=-\int p\space\text{d}p=\text{C}-\frac{p^2}{2}=\text{C}-\frac{u(x)^2}{2}$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{u'(x)^2}{2}=\text{C}-\frac{u(x)^2}{2}\Longleftrightarrow\int\frac{u'(x)}{\sqrt{\text{C}-u(x)^2}}\space\text{d}=\pm\int1\space\text{d}x$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to proceed is to simply guess that $u(x)$ is somewhat of the form $e^x$, since you know the second order derivative gives the negative of the original function, and any derivative of the exponential is itself

Next consider the complex exponential:

If you play around a little, you will see that $u(x)=ae^{ix}$ is a solution too, for any real $a$.

Use Euler's formula and you will get a solution in terms of sine and cosine.

Comment: is there a way to derive $u(x)=ae^{ix}$, without guessing it?

Comment: I don't know, there might be(I've had only one course in ODE). You could definitely find a proof which proves the general solution;  but it might not be constructive, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

To solve such a second order differential equation, you can somewhat "guess" in advance (make an educated guess).  For instance, in the following differential equation:

$$2u''(x) - u'(x) - u(x) = 0$$

$u(x) = e^{x}$ is clearly one solution.  But you want to find all of the solutions, so you suppose that, in general, a solution is of the form:

$$u(x)=Ae^{rx}$$

You can then differentiate it twice...

$$u'(x) = Are^{rx}$$
$$u''(x) = Ar^2e^{rx}$$

And plug it into your equation...

$$Ar^2e^{rx} + Ae^{rx} = 0$$
$$r^2 + 1 = 0$$

This reduces the problem to solving a quadratic equation, from which you can find the roots $(r_1,r_2)$.  In this case, the roots are imaginary:

$$r_1 = i$$
$$r_2 = -i$$

So your general solution is simply a linear combination of two solutions as follows:

$$u(x) = c_1e^{ix} + c_2e^{-ix}$$

From here on out, use Euler's equation to reduce the above equation to a linear combination of trig functions, like you had speculated.